# Why do I always see several marked for review but none in the queue?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, flags

In the top right you can see the "3" 
[image]

but the queues themmselves appear empty

Comment: Don't know for sure, but I believe it includes the ones in that count that you've already looked after.

Comment: Funny, I was just going to ask the same question - good thing I saw this.

Answer (score 4):

The number showing up is an aggregate number - it is items still in the queue waiting for resolution, including items you (personally) have already given your attention to.

So - there are three items in the queue, all of which you have seen already, but have not yet been fully handled (that is, other people need to see and act on, before they are cleared from the queue).

We are aware this aspect of the notification is confusing and are looking at ways of improving the experience.

Comment: I'm happy to read that last sentence. ;)